# Does the compiler generate a different type for each lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

> *Disclaimer:*  Do not use the code in this question.  It invokes undefined behaviour.  The core statement of the question, whether the compiler generates a new type for each lambda, and the corresponding answer remain valid.

To take get a function pointer to a lambda with a capture I came up with the following trick:

```
auto f = [&a] (double x) { return a*x; };
static auto proxy = f;
double(*ptr)(double) = [] (double x) { return proxy(x); };
// do something with ptr
```

I assign the lambda with a capture (which might be a function parameter) to a static variable inside the function, so I do not have to capture it when using it in the other lambda.  The other captureless lambda can then happily decay to a function pointer which I can pass to some shared library.

Now one could attempt to generalize this:

```
template < typename F >
decltype(auto) get_ptr(F f)
{
  static auto proxy = f;
  return [] (auto ... args) { return proxy(args...); };
}
```

However, as `proxy` is a static variable it will be overwritten on each call to the function.  Because it is a template, I think that it will be overwritten only when I call the same instantiation, i.e. each instantiation has it's own static `proxy`.

Nevertheless, the following works:

```
#include <cassert>

template < typename F >
decltype(auto) get_ptr(F f)
{
  static auto proxy = f;
  return [] (auto ... args) { return proxy(args...); };
}

int main()
{
  auto f1 = [ ](double,double) { return 1; };
  auto f2 = [=](double,double) { return 2; };
  auto f3 = [&](double,double) { return 3; };
  auto f4 = [&](double,double) { return 4; };
  auto f5 = [ ](double,double) { return 5; };

  int(*p1)(double,double) = get_ptr(f1);
  int(*p2)(double,double) = get_ptr(f2);
  int(*p3)(double,double) = get_ptr(f3);
  int(*p4)(double,double) = get_ptr(f4);
  int(*p5)(double,double) = get_ptr(f5);

  assert( p1(0,0) == 1 );
  assert( p2(0,0) == 2 );
  assert( p3(0,0) == 3 );
  assert( p4(0,0) == 4 );
  assert( p5(0,0) == 5 );
}
```

This looks suspicious as for `get_ptr(f1)` and `get_ptr(f5)` one might expect the same types to be deduced.  However, lambdas are compiler generated structs and it seems as if the compiler would generate a different type for each lambda, regardless of whether previous lambdas look like they could be reused.

So the above trick would be extremely useful for me under the condition that the compiler will definitely generate a different type for each lambda.  If this is not the case the generalisation of my hack is useless.

Comment: `f1` and `f5` can't be the same types anyway because one lambda returns 1 and the other returns 5. Their `operator()` implementations are necessarily different.

Comment: The (draft) spec says the following (in 5.1.2.3): _The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the closure type_...

Comment: @Yuushi Perfect.  Please write an answer!

Comment: I liked this generalized question about how the compiler handles and treats lambdas along with the comments and the accepted answer for this makes for a great reference to look back at. I made this a favorite of mine!

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think it invokes undefined behaviour. It's defined behaviour, but (per my answer) possibly *surprising* behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. Stack overflow is showing my first comment, but not my correction, by default. So I'll delete the two comments, and summarise that the pointer you get from the conversion stays valid even after the lambda is destroyed, per [expr.prim.lambda.closure/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the draft spec (n3376 specifically), *5.1.2.3* (emphasis mine).

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**, unnamed non-union class type — called the closure type...

Answer (score 2):

What you've effectively done is created a singleton holding a copy of the lambda, distinct for each type of lambda (which per [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1) means every lambda expression). This works generally because lambdas are immutable, however, a mutable lambda would reveal the difference:

```
auto f6 = [i = 1]( double, double ) mutable { return 6 * i++; };
int(*p6)(double,double) = get_ptr(f6);

assert( p6(0,0) == 6 );
assert( p6(0,0) == 12 );

int(*p6_prime)(double,double) = get_ptr(f6);
assert( p6_prime(0,0) == 18 ); // (!) p6_prime === p6
assert( p6(0,0) == 24 );

assert( f6(0,0) == 6 );
assert( f6(0,0) == 12 );
assert( f6(0,0) == 18 );
assert( f6(0,0) == 24 );
```

[Live demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Qw9tyPpN0EZn6AhJ)

The reason for this is an incorrect assumption in your original write-up:

> However, as proxy is a static variable it will be overwritten on each call to the function.

That's not true. The `static` variable is set once, the first time the function is called. Further calls to the same function will not evaluate the statement, so `proxy` will retain the value from the first time that particular template instantiation of `get_ptr` is called.

Normally you could separate the `static` declaration and assignment, but in this case you can't because lambdas don't have a default constructor (yet). If you did that, then calling `get_ptr` a second time on a lambda would reset the lambda that the *first* call's returned pointer was using, changing the above result to have:

```
int(*p6_prime)(double,double) = get_ptr(f6);
assert( p6_prime(0,0) == 6 );
assert( p6(0,0) == 12 ); // (!) p6 === p_prime
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments. Yes, indeed, I also noticed that there are all kinds of problems with this code. Nevertheless, the core of my question, does the compiler generate a different type for each lambda, was answered. I will probably edit the question some time soon, so nobody gets the idea to actually use this code.

Comment: @HenriMenke telling you a secret: what we do when we arrive here: we read the title of your question (1 line), we jump to the answer immediately, "ok". move on with life. don't bother editing, just keep your original content for historical integrity.

Comment: @v.oddou I did keep the original.  I only added a disclaimer above.