# Generic lambda in GCC

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

> *Disclaimer:*  Do not use the code in this question.  It invokes undefined behaviour.  The core statement of the question, why GCC struggles with type deduction, remains valid.

I use the following trick to get a function pointer to a lambda with a capture (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970960)).  The code compiles with Clang but not with GCC.  Is my code non-standard or is it a bug in GCC?

```
template < typename F >
decltype(auto) get_ptr(F f)
{
  static auto proxy = f;
  return [] (auto ... args) { return proxy(args...); };
}

double test()
{
  double a = 5;
  auto f = [&a](double x) { return a*x; };

  double(*p)(double) = get_ptr(f);

  return p(1);
}
```

Example on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/3qWdMH

Comment: Looks like GCC doesn't want to infer the type properly, but if you specify things explicitly, it seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/g/HFAIB7).

Comment: It works if you use `static auto F proxy = f;`, so it looks like gcc is trying to deduce the return type of `get_ptr` *before* it deduced the type of that `static auto proxy`. Seems like a gcc bug, unless someone can come up with standards wording that mandates such an ordering.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is broken. Consider:

```
double test(double a)
{
  auto f = [&a](double x) { return a*x; };

  double(*p)(double) = get_ptr(f);

  return p(1);
}

int main() {
    test(5); // ok, 5
    test(6); // UB, captured reference to `a` is now dangling, or, if captured by value, will return 5 when it should be 6
}
```

Comment: This is true.  Thank you very much for pointing that out.  However, that does not answer the question why the code does not compile with GCC.

Comment: @HenriMenke while that is indeed technically true, my answer largely invalidates your question. After all, why would you care why something doesn't work when you can't use it anyway.

Comment: Actually, your counter example is wrong.  You have to capture `a` by value to break it.

Comment: @HenriMenke you have to capture by value to break it the way I described above. Capturing by reference is actually even worse since reference becomes dangling after the first call, and you invoke UB when accessing it on second call. It just so happens that new `a` is at the same memory location. At least when you capture by value results are well defined.